# Reduce distance between an imageView and a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I've defined both this an imageview and a button this way in my linearlayout:

```
  <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageView2"

                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                                android:layout_weight=".1"
                                android:src="@drawable/clock"/>

                        <Button
                                android:id="@+id/buttonEntryHour"
                                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                                android:layout_weight=".33"
                                android:onClick="clickTimePicker1"
                                android:text="@string/otrosEntryHourText"
                                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

But they show in an unwanted way, like this:

[image]

I'd like the distance between the icon and the text to be reduced, so it displays like something like this:

[image]

How could be something like that achieved?

Comment: horizontal bias 0 ? it's all in basic ConstraintLayout documentation

Comment: remove the `layout_weight` from the views.

Comment: show also linear layout parent code. `layout_weight` may cause this issue

Comment: Instead of using `ImageView` why don't you use `android:drawableStart=""` inside your `Button`

Comment: Really don't use 2 views today. No reason to do that. Use a `Button` with the `android:drawableStart` attribute as suggested by Nilesh or the official `MaterialButton` as described below in my answer.

Comment: why don't you use drawableLeft attribute of TextView? it is easy way to achieve this work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue in your layout is the use of  `android:layout_weight`. Remove them.

But just use the [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) with the **`app:icon`** attribute, instead of 2 views:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        android:text="Button"
        ../>
```

[image]

You can customize the padding between icon and button text using the    **`app:iconPadding`** attribute.

Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        app:iconPadding="xxdp"
        android:text="Button"
        ../>
```

You can also use the `TextButton.Icon` style:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        android:text="Button"
        ../>
```

[image]

or an `OutlinedButton.Icon` style:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
    android:text="Button"
    ../>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

    <Button

            android:id="@+id/buttonEntryHour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="clickTimePicker1"
            android:text="otrosEntryHourText"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

No Need to put that in a `linearLayout` use drawableStart

```
<Button
                                android:id="@+id/buttonEntryHour"
                                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                                android:layout_weight=".33"
                                android:onClick="clickTimePicker1"
                                android:text="@string/otrosEntryHourText"
                                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
                            android:drawableStart="@drawable/clock"/>
```

And if you want to add some space to it, use `drawablePadding`

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout as a button instead of using the default Button object since you need few customizations.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:onClick="someMethod"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TEST CLICK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a linear layout you don't need the layout constraint code in your button (the last two lines). Also, you don't need the layout weights. All you need is a horizontal linear layout and add the ImageView first and the Button second. They will be displayed next to each other. You can add a margin if you want them a little more spread out. 
A mock example would be: 
    `<ImageView
         android:layout_width="30dp"
         android:layout_height="30dp"/>
    <Button
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
         android:text="Button Text"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Here i assume that you want to get both image and text together and want them to act as like a button.

If my assumption is true then please find below code.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivFacebook"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook"
                    android:tint="@drawable/textview_selector_social" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFacebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_33sdp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/facebookLogin"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/textview_selector_social"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFacebookLogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_social_selector"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:textColor="@drawable/textview_selector_social" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

**Result is here**

[image]

Comment: 4 views to have a button with text and icon?

Comment: To customize TextView and ImageViews position if required, otherwise your answer is perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this .You will achieve exactly what you want

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clock"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEntryHour"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clickTimePicker1"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Using Linear Layout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDemo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="Demo Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this
Using Relative Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDemo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="Demo Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```xml
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/clock" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEntryHour"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clickTimePicker1"
        android:text="@string/otrosEntryHourText"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

It should look like this:

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swdcc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please make the width of the ImageView to 0dp like the Button, and put in mind that the some layout_weight in a LinearLayout should be equal to 1. So if you have only this two Views on your layout make the some of their layout_weight to 1 (0.7 and 0.3 or 0.5 and 0.5...).
Try with the below code:

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:src="@drawable/clock"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEntryHour"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:onClick="clickTimePicker1"
        android:text="@string/otrosEntryHourText"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: When using LinearLayout, you don't need to use this two attribute:
\n
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"